# JSF + Hibernate serverError: class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf

I have created a very simple CRUD application using JSF, Hibernate and integrated them with MySQL. Problem is, whenever I try to add new data, I get the following exception:

```
serverError: class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException Target Unreachable, identifier 'customer' resolved to null
```

Here's my view:

```
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF Hibernate CRUD Example</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid id="panel1" columns="2" border="1"
                         cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Add Customer Information"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel value="First Namer:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{customer.firstName}" id="fn"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Last Name:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{customer.lastName}" id="ln"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Email:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{customer.email}" id="eml"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{customer.sd}" id="s"/>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{customer.msg}" id="msg" styleClass="msg"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{customer.saveCustomer}">
                    <f:ajax render="fn ln eml s msg" execute="@form"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>

        <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="2" border="1"
                             cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Update/Delete Customer Info"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Select Customer:"/>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{customer.selectedname}" id="ulist">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{customer.allCustomers}"/>
                        <f:ajax event="change" render="cid fname lname email sd" listener="#{customer.fullInfo}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                      <h:outputLabel value="Customer ID:"/>
                      <h:inputText value="#{customer.custId}" id="cid" readonly="true"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="First Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{customer.firstName}" id="fname"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Last Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{customer.lastName}" id="lname"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Email:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{customer.email}" id="email"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{customer.sd}" id="sd"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{customer.msg}" id="msg2" styleClass="msg"/>
                        <h:commandButton value="Update Info" action="#{customer.updateCustomer}">
                            <f:ajax render="ulist cid fname lname email sd msg2" execute="@form"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:commandButton value="Delete Info" action="#{customer.deleteCustomer}">
                            <f:ajax render="ulist cid fname lname email sd msg2" execute="@form"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </f:facet>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Here's my entity class - `Customer.java`:

```
package com.javaknowledge.entity;

import com.javaknowledge.dao.CustomerDao;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Capt. Jack Sparrow, Pirate Lord of the Caribbean
 */
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer custId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private String sd, msg, selectedname;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date dob) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getSd() {
        return sd;
    }

    public void setSd(String sd) {
        this.sd = sd;
    }

    public Integer getCustId() {
        return this.custId;
    }

    public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getSelectedname() {
        return selectedname;
    }

    public void setSelectedname(String selectedname) {
        this.selectedname = selectedname;
    }

    public void saveCustomer() {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(sd);
            System.out.println(d);
            this.dob = d;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.addCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Saved Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public void updateCustomer() {
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse(sd);
            System.out.println(d);
            this.dob = d;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.updateCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Update Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public void deleteCustomer() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.deleteCustomer(custId);
        this.msg = "Member Info Delete Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> users = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        users = dao.getAllCustomers();
        return users;
    }

    public void fullInfo() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        List<Customer> lc = dao.getCustomerById(selectedname);
        System.out.println(lc.get(0).firstName);
        this.custId = lc.get(0).custId;
        this.firstName = lc.get(0).firstName;
        this.lastName = lc.get(0).lastName;
        this.email = lc.get(0).email;
        this.dob = lc.get(0).dob;
        this.sd = sdf.format(dob);
    }

    private void clearAll() {
        this.firstName = "";
        this.lastName = "";
        this.sd = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.custId = 0;
    }
}
```

And my *addCustomer*() method in DAO class:

```
public void addCustomer(Customer cust) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(cust);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

What is the reason behind my getting that exception?

P.S. I am a complete beginner in JSF and Hibernate.

**EDIT - 1:**

This code was generated later:

```
package javax.faces.bean;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE})
@Inherited
public @interface ManagedBean {

    public String name() default "";

    public boolean eager() default false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have your `Customer` class managed by JSF or container (CDI) in your real code (I expect because you have these import statements : `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;`)? It does not have any annotations in your current code. The class is just a plain class. It is currently not being managed - it is neither a JSF managed bean nor a CDI managed bean that it must be (either one of them).

Comment: @Tiny Ok. It's supposed to be a JSF managed code, it's actually a tutorial I found in a site. Nothing about annotations were mentioned there. Ok, I'll try adding JSF annotations and inform you of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Customer entity is hibernate mapped entity do not try to add it to spring container or make it managed bean by somr other way. You should create another class called something like CustomerBackingBean and define there customer as a field. Also some method should exist to load customer from db using your dao. After it is loaded you will be able to see it on the page.

You should try and think on your own to completelly understand how it will works :).
Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I understood your problem I got the same error then I solved it. 
problem is customer.firstName in index have no target (ctrl+Click on customer.firstName in index.xhml) you don't have target there.

for this Customer.java file is a java class file, but according to JSF we need to create Managed bean file (name:Customer.java). How to create it if you don't know follow my steps(first copy code in Customer.java then delete that file )

```
step 1: Right-click on the com.knowledge.entity source package node and choose New > Other.
Step 2: Select JSF Managed Bean from the JavaServer Faces category. Click Next.
Step 3: Type Customer for the Class Name.
Step 4: You will use the Managed Bean name Customer as the value for the inputText and commandButton in the JSF page index.xhtml when calling methods in the bean.
Step 5: Select com.javaknowledge.entity for the Package.
Step 6: Type customer for the Name that will be used for the managed bean.
Step 7: Set Scope to Session. Click Finish.
```

that's it.